# Cómo ordenar por año y mes en MongoDB

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo una modelo llamado "factura" con los siguientes campos: total, fecha_venta, cliente_factura.
Estoy utilizando un $group para ordenarlos por año y luego por mes para obtener el total. Pero solo me lo aplica por mes

```
Reporte.aggregate(
        [
            {$group :
                {_id: {$year: "$fecha_venta"}, _id:{$month:"$fecha_venta"}, total:{$sum: '$total'}}
            }
        ]
    )
```

me devuelve lo siguiente

```
"factura": [
        {
            "_id": 9,
            "total": 55875
        },
        {
            "_id": 2,
            "total": 3000
        },
        {
            "_id": 4,
            "total": 1850
        }
```

Pero no me ordena por año y luego los meses
me gustaría ordenarlos así

```
"factura": [
        {
            "_id": 2018{
                _id: 2
                total:3000

                _id: 4
                total:3000 
  
                 _id: 9
                total:55875
            },
             "_id": 2019{
                _id: 1
                total:xxx

                _id: 2
                total:xxx 
  
                 _id: 3
                total:xxxx
            },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea agrupar una colección de documentos por año y mes, para ello se utiliza un proceso de agregación.

La salida que dices que quieres, no es un documento válido, sin embargo imagino que lo que intentas lograr es un documento que agrupe en una lista las ventas por año, y cada documento que representa el año a su vez contenga una lista con documentos agrupados por los meses de dicho año.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución está en realizar un filtrado un poco más completo, ya que deseas los datos por año y mes, y actualmente los estás filtrando por año , pero luego reescribes el campo `_id` para filtrar por mes y por eso el resultado obtenido.

**Agrupar**

Debemos tener en cuenta el tipo de agrupamiento que deseamos lograr, en este caso deseamos que nos agrupe todas las ventas del mes y del año. Por lo cual lo apropiado es pasar como campo `_id` una composición de dichos campos, por ejemplo:

```
$group: {
  _id: {
    year: {
      $year: "$fecha_venta"
    },
    mes: {
      $month: "$fecha_venta"
    }
  },
  ventas: {
    $push: {
      total: "$total",
    }
  }
}
```

Estamos construyendo un campo `_id` que será el que indique que tipo de agrupación queremos, en este caso, se agruparán los documentos cuya fecha coincida en año y mes. Todos los elementos que pertenezcan a dicho grupo serán añadidos al campo `ventas` el cual simplemente contendrá el total de la venta de cada documento.

Podemos ver el resultado de la etapa de agregación anterior en el siguiente [MongoPlayGround](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mAJxIJVlUdo).

Se obtiene un documento parecido al siguiente:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "mes": 2,
      "year": 2019
    },
    "ventas": [
      {
        "total": 19875.45
      },
      {
        "total": 145.25
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "mes": 1,
      "year": 2019
    },
    "ventas": [
      {
        "total": 12345.45
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Como se observa, la lista de `ventas` contiene los valores de ventas del mes. Y los datos están correctamente agrupados por año y mes.

**Reducir**

Ahora que ya tenemos los totales agrupados por año y mes, debemos sumar los totales de venta que se muestran en cada elemento de la lista de ventas. Para lograrlo usaremos el operador [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/), que usaremos dentro de una etapa [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/). En esta etapa, también nos desharemos del campo `_id` creado anteriormente y crearemos 2 nuevos campos: `year` y `mes`, para poder luego agrupar los elementos resultantes:

```js
{
  $project: {
    _id: 0, // <- nos deshacemos del campo _id
    year: "$_id.year", // <- creamos el campo year
    mes: "$_id.mes",   //    y el campo mes
    total: {  // <- campo que almacenará el total del proceso de reducción
      $reduce: {
        input: "$ventas",  // <- array de entrada
        initialValue: 0,   // <- valor inicial para acumular la reducción
        in: {
          $sum: [
            "$$value",     // <- se refiere al valor inicial que se irá acumulando
            "$$this.total" // <- campo que se sumará en cada iteración
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hecho esto, ahora tenemos los documentos agrupados por año y mes y cuyos totales se corresponden al total de ventas de dicho mes en el año.

La salida puede verse algo parecida a la siguiente:

```js
[
  {
    "mes": 2,
    "total": 1630.19,
    "year": 2020
  },
  {
    "mes": 3,
    "total": 895,
    "year": 2020
  },
  {
    "mes": 1,
    "total": 2875.05,
    "year": 2020
  },
  {
    "mes": 2,
    "total": 20020.7,
    "year": 2019
  },
  {
    "mes": 1,
    "total": 12345.45,
    "year": 2019
  }
]
```

Un ejemplo del proceso anterior se puede apreciar en el siguiente [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y1y6avEu7lP)

**Reagrupar (o volver a agrupar)**

Los resultados obtenidos hasta ahora se parecen bastante a los que deseamos, solo falta agrupar los registros por año y que la lista de `ventas` contenga un documento con el total de ventas de cada mes. Para ello usaremos nuevamente una etapa `$group`, como la siguiente:

```js
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$year",
    ventas: {
      $push: {
        mes: "$mes",
        total: "$total"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

La salida de el proceso anterior se puede ver como la siguiente:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": 2019,
    "ventas": [
      {
        "mes": 1,
        "total": 12345.45
      },
      {
        "mes": 2,
        "total": 20020.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": 2020,
    "ventas": [
      {
        "mes": 2,
        "total": 1630.19
      },
      {
        "mes": 3,
        "total": 895
      },
      {
        "mes": 1,
        "total": 2875.05
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

La cual es la salida esperada, donde cada campo `_id` se corresponde al año, y cada elemento de la lista `ventas` es un documento que contiene el número del mes y el total de ventas de dicho mes.

Puedes ver la implementación final en el siguiente [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UTiTB8ueicz)

El código completo de las etapas de agregación sería el siguiente:

```js
Reporte.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: {
          $year: "$fecha_venta"
        },
        mes: {
          $month: "$fecha_venta"
        }
      },
      ventas: {
        $push: {
          total: "$total",
          
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      year: "$_id.year",
      mes: "$_id.mes",
      total: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$ventas",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $sum: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this.total"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$year",
      ventas: {
        $push: {
          mes: "$mes",
          total: "$total"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: +1 no conocia el MongoPlayground

Comment: Sólo trabaja con `find()` y con `aggregate()`, pero con eso basta para mostrar algunas cosas, @JackNavaRow.